# Restricting the size of a schema in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

We use Amazon Redshift in our project.

In our project, we have assigned different schemas to different teams. For example, marketing gets a separate schema to store their tables for analysis, while the sales team gets a separate schema.

What is happening is that the analysts from one group use up majority of the database's space with tables which are more temporary in nature and don't care to drop it/purge it. So, the discipline to maintain their own schemas is left with the individual schema owners. Every now and then, we end up doing a housekeeping exercise.

I wanted to know if we can configure the size per schema/database. Let's say, we allot 100 GB to the sales schema, 50 GB to marketing and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature now exists in Redshift:
[Redshift Create Schema Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_SCHEMA.html#r_CREATE_SCHEMA-parameters)

Relevant example from the docs:

```
create schema us_sales authorization dwuser QUOTA 50 GB;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Redshift docs, Redshift seems not to provide a feature to restrict the size per schema/database, but there is a workaround.

Since you can get the data size per table with the following query, you can write a script which monitors their usage and send an alert if exceeded. Then, simply run the script periodically through cron.

- Query to get data size and number of rows per table

```sql
select
  trim(pgdb.datname) as database, trim(pgn.nspname) as schema,
  trim(a.name) as Table, b.mbytes, a.rows
from
  (select db_id, id, name, sum(rows) as rows from stv_tbl_perm a group by db_id, id, name) as a
  join pg_class as pgc on pgc.oid = a.id
  join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace
  join pg_database as pgdb on pgdb.oid = a.db_id
  join (select tbl, count(*) as mbytes from stv_blocklist group by tbl) b on a.id=b.tbl
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

- ex) Result

```sql
 database |     schema    |    table    | mbytes |   rows
----------+---------------+-------------+--------+----------+
 test_db  | dev_schmea_1  | click_log   |     23 |     4653
 prod_db  | prod_schema_1 | click_log   |  16217 |  2112354
 prod_db  | prod_schema_1 | install_log |   5544 |   433538
```

- Query to get data size and number of rows per schema

```sql
select
  trim(pgdb.datname) as database, trim(pgn.nspname) as schema,
  sum(b.mbytes) as mbytes, sum(a.rows) as rows
from
  (select db_id, id, name, sum(rows) as rows from stv_tbl_perm a group by db_id, id, name) as a
  join pg_class as pgc on pgc.oid = a.id
  join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace
  join pg_database as pgdb on pgdb.oid = a.db_id
  join (select tbl, count(*) as mbytes from stv_blocklist group by tbl) b on a.id=b.tbl
group by pgdb.datname, pgn.nspname
order by 1, 2;
```

- Query to get data size and number of rows per database

```sql
select
  trim(pgdb.datname) as database, sum(b.mbytes) as mbytes, sum(a.rows) as rows
from
  (select db_id, id, name, sum(rows) as rows from stv_tbl_perm a group by db_id, id, name) as a
  join pg_class as pgc on pgc.oid = a.id
  join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace
  join pg_database as pgdb on pgdb.oid = a.db_id
  join (select tbl, count(*) as mbytes from stv_blocklist group by tbl) b on a.id=b.tbl
group by pgdb.datname
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helps as a workaround.